# UITableViewCell Doesn't display loaded data but displays it when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing a weird issue and I am sure I am doing something wrong. In my UITableViewController class I have a function as follows:

```
-(void)EERefreshView
{
    NSLog(@"App delegate requested the view be refreshed");
    [self loadEventsFromDB];

    for(int a=0;a<eventsList.count;a++)
    {

        DB_EEEvent *event = (DB_EEEvent*)eventsList[a];
        UITableViewCell *cell =
        [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        //NSLog(@"CellID %@", cell.reuseIdentifier);


        //get references to the UI components
        UILabel *lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
        UILabel *lblDate = (UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:6];
        UIImageView *imgEvent = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:7];

        //set values
        lblTitle.text = event.name;

        lblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",
                        event.startdate,event.enddate];

        AppDelegate *del = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]; //need this to get the BaseURL

        // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
        NSString * imageURL =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@%@",del.api.BaseURL,event.logo];
        NSString* webStringURL = [imageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

        [imgEvent setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
            //do somethign when image call completes
        }];

        [eventsListCells addObject:cell];

        if(a == selectedEvent)
        {


        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tblEventsList reloadData];
    });

}
```

This function loads an array with UITableViewCell objects which is then used later on by

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell data
    NSLog(@"IndexPathRow: %d", indexPath.row);
    UITableViewCell *cell =  (UITableViewCell*)eventsListCells[indexPath.row];
    return cell;


}
```

However when the cell is loaded lblTitle and lblDate have no text displaying in them. But when I tap on a cell it then displays the text in the labels. So this means that the data is there but its not being refresh when initially created. I suspect this might have something to do with threads but I am not an expert on the subject and would appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: why calling `[tblEventsList reloadData];` in dispatch async?

Comment: @HRM Because the TableView UI is updated in the main thread. If I don't use that then the table view will not update automatically and remains blank until I scroll it. By the way I did try calling [tblEventList reloadData] without the async block and even after scrolling the text doesn't load unless I click on the cell. It seems to have something to do with the clicking

Comment: try to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with different identifier. e.g. `[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%i", a]];`

Comment: Pull the `[tblEventsList reloadData];` out completely. Let the view refresh itself once, and see what happens. I'm wondering if you're altering the cells in your `async` call, while the `UITableView` is also trying to display them. You should create the cells, give them to the table, then stop touching them. Does this `EERefreshView` method just get called repeatedly, over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what is bothering you and why you created this method, but you don't need it. The only reason why you need back thread is your image loading so that should be thrown in bkg. thread and the rest of the code should be in -

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.
```

U really don't need to pre create cells, and U cant cause they are reusable. For example if you have 50 elements in eventsList and room for only 5 cell on your screen you cant create 50 cells cause the code will create only 5+1 and reuse them as they appear on the screen, so every element of your eventsList will use one of those 5 cells and on the other side every cell will be a host for 10 different elements from your eventsList array. So as you can see your code doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @AntonioDev Thanks that does make sense but then why does it show the data when I click on it?

Comment: I really don't know, but your problem is trivial and "already been done" in most of the UITableViews out there so I really don't see the point in debugging your code, read the docs, google it, I am sure you'll find lots of functional examples... Try IconDownloader class (you have it on GitHub), study the example and that is it. You will reuse this code many, many times...

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your insight into the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The second function you mentioned in your question is the function that is called to populate the table with data.  When you call `[tblEventsList reloadData];` your app just calls the `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.  So this method needs to be outputting data back to the table.  A very simple example is below. Also, make sure your table delegate and data source are set.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
           initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.your_data_source objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kyle. I am aware of the fact that reloadData is in effect calling cellForRowAtIndex. The issue I am facing is that I have already created an array of cells that I want to use. When I return one of the cells form that array in my cellForRoWAtIndex function it doesn't load up the text from it.

Comment: -1: His implementation of this method *is* giving cells back to the table, they've just already been created elsewhere.

Comment: That seems very odd, as a quick debug tip, print out your array in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  Make sure that it is alloced and is not null.  There might be some weird issue where the array is null upon load but then gets set when the user doesn't some action.